# Amazon RDS encryption questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Since AMAZON RDS supports encrypting your database. Does anyone know after encryption, can I still query my data?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can. Would it make any sense if you could not get your data back after uploading to the db?

Comment: The encryption is at RDS server end and the client application querying data dont have to deal with encryption/decryption. It happens automatically. I would suggest going through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

Comment: I can understand that somehow we can still send queries like exact match. However, how to deal with other queries like range queries? The AWS encrypts with 256AES, and no property of plaintext has been preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RDS **encrypts data at rest** (on disk).

Once it is read from disk, it is automatically decrypted.

Your queries will operate the same as a non-encrypted database. The encryption is transparent from SQL.

Comment: I really want to know if RDS can handle range query. I read the document that RDS uses 256-AES to do the encryption. That is, no property of the plaintext has been preserved. If I query select *** from ** where *** > 100. RDS has no idea which values are greater than 100 unless it decrypts the whole table and then answers the query. Decrypting the whole tables looks inefficient for me.

Comment: All plaintext is preserved. To a user of the database, there is no difference whether data is encrypted or decrypted. The encryption is done when the data is written to, or read from, disk. See: [Encrypting Amazon RDS resources - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)

Comment: Thank you, I think I have some understanding now. Just two more questions. First, if the data is encrypted, will the index still work? That is, to answer a query, will the whole table be read? Another one is, does RDS and MySQL (with encryption option on) use the same/similar principles?

Comment: It will behave exactly as if there was no encryption. It has no impact on your usage of the database. All SQL functionality will work 100% the same. It _might_ cause a slight slowdown of data access. I can only point you to the above documentation of how encryption is done.